# about the IF statements

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, square-root

When I enter the values for a, b c which are 1.0, 3 1 the answer should be only , saying that The roots are -0.381 and -2.62803. I get both of the answers and I also get "There are no real roots". I think I am using IF statements in a wrong way. Please be kind enough to explain me where I go wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sha {
public static void main(String[] args ){
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a , b , and c : ");
double a = input.nextDouble();
double b = input.nextDouble();
double c = input.nextDouble();

// the equations 
double discriminant = Math.pow (b , 2) - 4 * a * c;
double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/2 * a ;
double root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/2 * a ;

if (discriminant > 0 ){
System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}
if (discriminant == 0 ){
System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
}
else  {
System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
}




}
}
```

Comment: You're missing an else.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
if (discriminant > 0 ) {
  System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}
else if (discriminant == 0 ) {
  System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
}
else {
  System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
}
```

Your code is currently  running as follows:

```
// first if group
if (discriminant > 0 ) {
  System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}

// second if group
if (discriminant == 0 ) {
  System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
}
// handle everything else for second if group only
else {
  System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
}
```

It should run as this:

```
// one if group
if (discriminant > 0 ) {
  System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}
else {
  // second if condition in else statement
  if (discriminant == 0 ) {
    System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
  }
  // handle everything else
  else {
    System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you gave me works .I have seen another code , which has used only the if and it works .. do u know why ?

Comment: @user3196297 Without the `else if`, the same condition, `discriminant > 0`, which prints the line you expect, ensures the next `if` condition is false causing the line to be printed in the `else` clause. Adding the other `else` to form an `else if` turns these `if` statements into a three-way conditional which is what you appear to require in this sample code.

Comment: @user3196297 That code probably has a one-way `if` condition, followed directly by a two-way `if` condition.  This is a three-way `if` condition, which needs a (slightly) different technique.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `if`, `else if` and `else` in your code. Then only the control will execute only one loop which condition turned true at first and ignore the other `else if` and `else` loops. Otherwise, the condition test will happen in all the `if` loops and *execute the statements in loop if the conditional test passes*, no matter whether a prior loop statements got executed or not

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more verbose syntax will help make this clear:

```
if discriminant > 0
then
   print ...
end if

if discriminant == 0
then
   print ...
else
   print ...
end if
```

So I hope you can see that the else part is only applied if discriminant is not zero and the if statement of discriminant > 0 is independent of the first if-statement.

Thus you should rewrite your code as follows:

```
if (discriminant > 0 ){
   System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}
else if (discriminant == 0 ){
   System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
}
else  {
   System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
}
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) for more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

you use two if and one else. In this case first check with first condition. Then with next if.if that comes false also comes controller in that else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sha {
public static void main(String[] args ){
Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a , b , and c : ");
double a = input.nextDouble();
double b = input.nextDouble();
double c = input.nextDouble();

// the equations 
double discriminant = Math.pow (b , 2) - 4 * a * c;
double root1 = (-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant))/2 * a ;
double root2 = (-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant))/2 * a ;

if (discriminant > 0 ){
System.out.printf("The roots are %8.6f and %8.6f ", root1, root2);
}
else if (discriminant == 0 ){
System.out.print("The root is  " +  root1);
}
else  {
System.out.print("There are no real roots ");
}




}
}
```